# Acpitool no information

Tags: linux, acpi

When I run as root `acpitool` I recieved

```
 Battery is not present, bailing out. 
  AC adapter     : <info not available> 
  Thermal info   : <not available>
```

I can understand why all the acpi modules are compiled in the kernel (3.14.4), 
this is the output of `cat /boot/config | grep acpi` I get

```
CONFIG_ACPI_AC=y
CONFIG_ACPI_BATTERY=y
CONFIG_ACPI_BUTTON=y
CONFIG_ACPI_VIDEO=m
CONFIG_ACPI_FAN=y
CONFIG_ACPI_DOCK=y
CONFIG_ACPI_PROCESSOR=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_IPMI is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_HOTPLUG_CPU=y
CONFIG_ACPI_PROCESSOR_AGGREGATOR=m
CONFIG_ACPI_THERMAL=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_PCI_SLOT is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_CONTAINER=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_SBS is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_HED is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_APEI is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_EXTLOG is not set
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ_CPB=y
# CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI is not set
CONFIG_PNPACPI=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDEACPI=y
CONFIG_ATA_ACPI=y
CONFIG_PATA_ACPI=y
# ACPI drivers
CONFIG_GPIO_ACPI=y
# ACPI drivers
CONFIG_SENSORS_ACPI_POWER=m
# CONFIG_ACPI_INT3403_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_ACPI is not set
CONFIG_DMA_ACPI=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_QUICKSTART is not set
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI=m
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_ALSA_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_DEBUGFACILITIES=y
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_UNSAFE_LEDS=y
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_VIDEO=y
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_HOTKEY_POLL=y
CONFIG_ACPI_WMI=y
CONFIG_ACPI_TOSHIBA=m
# CONFIG_ACPI_CMPC is not set
```

The ACPI_TOSHIBA module is loaded.The acpid daemon is running.
Can someone help me and suggest me how to investigate more in the problem?